# How to pass callback function to litelement from React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polymer, lit-element

I'm trying to use lit-element component in my React project, and I'd like to pass in the callback function to lit-element component from React but with no luck.

I've tried a couple of different ways, like change property type, and pass function in as a string, but none of them works.

**lit-element component code:**

```
import { LitElement, html } from "lit-element";

class MyButton extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      clickHandler: {
        type: String
      },
      bar: {
        type: String
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const foo = this.clickHandler; //value is undefined
    const bar = this.bar; //value is "it's bar"
    return html`
      <button @click=${this.clickHandler}>click me</button>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("my-button", MyButton);
```

**react side code:**

```
<my-button clickHandler={() => alert("clicked")} bar="it's bar" />
```

I put a break point in the render section of the component, and I can see the 'bar' value get passed in correctly, but the value of 'clickHandler' is undefined.

Does anyone have any idea on how to pass function from React to lit-element?

Thanks!

Comment: does it show alert "clicked" whenever my-button component is rendered ?

Answer (score 5):

This question probably isn't just valid for react. It's quite general, how do I pass a handler from parent to child component, either it's a lit-element or html element.

According to the property doc, https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties

```
<my-element 
  mystring="hello world"
  mynumber="5"
  mybool
  myobj='{"stuff":"hi"}'
  myarray='[1,2,3,4]'>
</my-element>
```

Doesn't seem that it supports (callback) function at the moment. So how does Element handle event from parent level ?

According to the event doc, https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events, you can dispatch any event to the dom tree, including your parent. `Dom` event system is much broader than `React` prop system.

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
    ...
    let event = new CustomEvent('my-event', {
      detail: {
        message: 'Something important happened'
      }
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

and then in either lit or non-lit context, use the following to handle the event,

```
const myElement = document.querySelector('my-element');
myElement.addEventListener('my-event', (e) => {console.log(e)});
```

This way you can allow children to fire implementation for parent, which is exactly the definition for callback.

Comment: @Steve, apology of not finishing my solution the first time. I edited my post, now it should solve the exact problem, instead of what the problem hinted. I really don't think the solution provided by other author so far is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

What I found that works is adding a ref in the react component to the lit element, then literally setting the property on it.

So, for the following JSX:

```
<some-webcomponent ref={this.myRef}></some-webcomponent>
```

You can pass a property to ‘some-webcomponent’ in i.e. componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount () {
  const element = this.myRef.current;
  element.someCallback = () => // ...
}
```

It’s not too pretty, but I wouldn’t consider it a hack either. Requires quite a lot of boilerplate though :/

Here’s a full React component for reference:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {   
  constructor(props) {     
    super(props);     
    this.myRef = React.createRef();   
  }   

  render() {     
    return <some-webcomponent ref={this.myRef}></some-webcomponent>;   
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    const element = this.myRef.current;  
    element.someCallback = () => console.log(“call!”);
  }
}
```

Where the lit element is:

```
import { LitElement, html } from "lit-element";  

class SomeWebcomponent extends LitElement {
   static get properties() {    
     return {       
      someCallback: { type: Function }
     };
   }

   render() {     
     return html`       
       <button @click=${this.someCallback}>click me</button>     
     `;   
    } 
}  

customElements.define("some-webcomponent", SomeWebcomponent);
```

Comment: Even though it's not 100% hack, it's still not how it's designed for, the answer i believe is through the native event handling, not `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the menu button click function for the no redux pwa-starter-kit at https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/blob/template-no-redux/src/components/my-app.js. I believe that provides the example that may work for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, It's best to include an example within your answer and not to just direct to an external link as links can become broken or be updated to non-relevant content.